# Max connection limit in php apache server

Tags: php, apache

I have 32 GB ubuntu server where my site is hosted. I have installed the XAMPP and running my site. So here my question is what is the limit of maximum concurrent connections apache will handle and how I can check that? At which extent I can increase it and how? 
My server must have 5000 concurrent users at a time So for that I have to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the formula is :

```
(Total available memory - Memory needed by operating system) / memory each PHP process needs.
```

Honestly it's a bit hard to predict sometimes, so it might be worth doing some experimentation. The goal is that you never use more memory that available, so your operating system never swaps.

However, you can also turn it around. 5000 concurrent requests is frankly a lot, so I'm going by your 5000 concurrent users.

Say if 5000 users are actively using your application at a given time, and maybe they do on average each 1 request every 30 seconds or so. And say that the average PHP script takes 100ms to execute.

That's about 166 requests per second made by your users. Given that it takes 100ms to fulfill a request, it means you need about 17 connections to serve all that up. Which is easy for any old server.

Anyway, the key to all these types of dilemmas is to:

- Make an educated guess
- Measure
- Make a better guess
- Repeat

Comment: in my old project I have same server configuration but for 5000 users it started to show too many http connection error, So I need info regarding how to increase max concurrent connection in xampp apache server, do you have any idea on that? I have google it but I am new to servers so not understand.

Comment: No sorry, I don't use XAMPP. I use generally use native ubuntu packages for this.